# wmi query on Win32_Account doesn't stop

Tags: vb.net, wmi

```
Dim obj As ManagementObject
Dim searchObj As New ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Account")

For Each obj In searchObj.Get()
   MsgBox(obj("Name"))
Next
```

I have a form that has the upper code in the Load event. This returns me about 23 accounts and then it stops and the form doesn't show. I guess that it still searches, but i let the app run for minutes and nothing.

Also for a test i've added a exit routine after it founds 15 accounts and the form shows.

Can anyone help me out?
I just want to find the accounts and to display them, but the routine runs forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in another forum:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Account WHERE LocalAccount = TRUE
```